# Mongo Shard Key Analysis

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Assuming a vast database with tons of shards, unique shard keys and all the sharding-quality goodies you'd want.

Let's take 3 string-type shard keys...

Key 1 -> 128.53ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ

Key 2 -> 128.53XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Key 3 -> 150.53ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ

Is it safe to assume mongo's algorithm that determines how "similar" shard keys are, puts both keys prefixed with 128.53 close to each other, and 150.53 further away?

As I see it, there are 2 possible ways mongo could be determining likeness between shard keys:

A) in totality, with all character differences getting equal weight

or

B) from left to right, with earlier characters being MORE important than letters characters (just as we analyze numbers... 101 and 100.999999 are much "closer" than 100.999999 and 30.999999)

Does anyone know which strategy they employ?

Comment: What do you think you mean by "..mongo's algorithm.."? You have if you want the ability to specify exactly where you expect the distribution between shards to actually go. In "real world" cases that is almost certainly the approach being by specific "range based" or "tag based" instead of default distribution on cardinality. And then there are "hashed" shard keys. So it's really way to broad a question for a meaningful answer here. [See the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/) and then read related articles. It also skates right on the edge of being DBA centric.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm talking range-based sharding, so that I can co-locate geo-similar data on the same servers. You imply that I'm unread on the subject, but I've read all of the manual articles and nowhere does it specifically state how it calculates differences between shard keys. And in my example above, I show how... both possibilities have wildly different actualizations... one which suits my application perfectly, the other the opposite result. see my edit

Comment: I'm not implying anything other than a very "airy and non specific" question which is way too broad. And if you're an "expert" on a subject then don't post questions without specific detail which are way too broad in scope. Comments are not for your long "counterpoints" to where people are prompting you to "be more specific" in your question. Your "Question" is where such informative detail belongs. Currently it's not there. Please do be far more specific and [edit your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50868502/edit)

Comment: @NeilLunn just targeted the question

Comment: Still way too broad. If you cannot be more specific to a case then it's just not something a meaningful and definitive answer can be given for. As you know, the documentation on this spans pages. And to be frank, you didn't even attempt to be more specific and are just adding trivial content in response to a close vote. If there's a meaningful question that applies "specifically" to a certain situation you need to implement it, then take the time to actually make that your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn frankly, it is not broad. there are 2 ways mongo could be analyzing shard key likeness... I'm asking which.

Comment: Shard key values are compared according to  [BSON Comparison/Sort Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/) rather than a likeness or similarity algorithm, so your string values will use a simple binary comparison. Chunk splits are determined based on data distribution; the `mongos` routing service will target requests to appropriate shard(s) based on query criteria. Is your goal to locate geo-similar data on specific shards because you have a deployment spanning multiple geos, or are you concerned about data locality for queries?

Comment: @Stennie yes exactly, both! I'm trying to cluster geo-similar data and make sure that find and update operations are targeted at the exact shards holding the data (to reduce noise).. by embedding some location data in the shard key + a unique random string at the end. I needed to know how the shard keys are analyzed so I make sure to accurately construct my keys for these aims. Please offer this up as the official answer!